# Stage Within Another Stage in javafx

Tags: javafx-2

All,

I am developing a client/server application in JavaFX.  I have a main menu in a primaryStage and would like to load the contents (Designed a form in Screen Builder) when a menu is clicked in another stage?  How do i do that?  Also, I wish to make my client stage window to fit the size of primaryStage I already have? I am new to JavaFX and thanks in advance for your help.

Regards
PK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of comments:

JavaFX is all about the client-side.  While it is billed as a library on which to base Rich Internet Apps, its current incarnation, imo, does not live up to this promise.  For enterprise-level client/server apps, you're likely to get better security and database flexibility by investing development time in the server-side middle-tier than by creating a heavyweight client-side app.  It's just the way things are right now.

Secondly, JavaFX 2.2 currently provides no support for a Visual Studio-esque "Multi-document Interface" or a GUI with parent windows that can contain child windows.

If what you want is to display a Modal Dialog Window after selecting an option in your primary stage, you can certainly do that.  Many people create helper classes to assist with the creation of modal dialogs because in JavaFX 2.2 it is a little awkward to create them.  The helper class I used for modal dialogs holds two pairs of references:

- References to the parent window's Stage and Controller object
- References to this dialog's Stage and Controller object

Having these references handy makes it simpler to create the modal stage and it provides the references you may need to pass data between the controller objects for the parent and modal dialogs.